# Steps between Wireframe / UI design for web development

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, website-design, css, interface-design

Based on my sketch/wireframe prepared for a UI designer (links below):

Link: http://postimg.org/image/npt5zlvu7/

1) Would I be able to approach a UI designer with the wireframe/sketch above?

2) What are the concerns that I should have between wireframe -> UI design -> front-end development?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post screenshots of your examples in case the URLs you posted go down in the future?

Comment: @Johannes Thanks for the note Johannes. The link expired but I replaced with a permanent URL for future reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly approach a UI designer with what you have.

The concerns I'd have is that UI design, Wireframing, Prototyping, Interaction Design, Content writing, Development, etc all influence each other.

In other words, it's very difficult to do any one of those tasks in isolation of another.

Wireframes can't fully predict all user flows. They can't stipulate all the interaction design. Sometimes the UI design leads to a solution that would change the wireframes, etc.

So, as long as you are OK with keeping the documents 'loose' I think you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to work more on information architecture and wireframing, don't make the interface too crowded, this will give the user a bad experience. Try to keep it as minimal as possible. For inspiration can visit [52 weeks of UX](http://52weeksofux.com/).

Read more learn more about HCI (human computer interaction), study human physiology to see things. If you want to be a UX designer you must read this book: **LEAN UX Applying Lean Principles to Improve User Experience**, by Jeff Gothelf and Josh Seiden.